# ReactJS.NET & Webpack Server-side Render w/Styles

Tags: c#, css, reactjs, webpack, reactjs.net

I am trying to render a component server-side for the initial page load. The markup gets rendered perfectly using @Html.React("componentName", props). The issue I am having is the component will render without styling. An instant later the styles get loaded through a Webpack bundle and the typical style-loader.

I have tried a couple approaches.

1. https://github.com/thereactivestack/style-collector-loader does not work because I get an error saying the global is undefined.
2. https://github.com/kriasoft/isomorphic-style-loader does not work for the same reason

Ideally I would like to get the required CSS from the components and render them into the razor view.

I am trying to fix a bug on an existing project. Webpack and react are relatively new concepts for me so I am not entirely sure what information I should provide. Let me know what additional details will help.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `require('your css file')` in **componentDidMount** function when trying to use server-side rendering.

for more info:
https://github.com/webpack/react-starter/issues/37